# How to send GET request with json body to play framework? - Java

Tags: java, json, http, playframework

I searched a lot for methods to send GET request with JSON body.. I know it doesn't go with the GET request specs but I'm required to do that anyway.

I managed to send the request with body using Curl, but now the body is not recognized by the play application.

I want to ask if I can do this using the play framework.

Thanks.

Comment: GET requests don't have bodies

Comment: It's technically possible to send a GET with a body. It will either be ignored or rejected though. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: Are you trying to send a GET with a body using Play or receive a GET with a body?

Comment: Thanks all.. @Ryan I'm trying to receive GET with a body

Comment: What error do you get when you load request.body? Or is it just empty/null?

Comment: @Nonos the body reaches the server as null

Comment: I have had DELETE with body working (although it's also not RESTful and is not supported in the test) but I could read the body ok.